# Get, customize and recompile the source code of PDFium extension present in Chrome/MS-Edge

Tags: javascript, c++, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge, pdfium

I know that the Pdf-viewer in Chrome and MS-Edge is basically an open source extension based on PDFium. I have read along the internet attempts of people trying to customize the built-in pdf-viewer e.g. changing the background color for a friendly night reading, trying to add new buttons to the UI, new context menu, etc. Most of them have a similar approach: Modify the existing plugin on the go and make the changes persistent. For instance, injecting javascript code to serve their purposes. The recurrent solution given was "Why bother? Go and use Pdf.js" but that implies to start a UI from scratch so for most people (me included) is not an option.

I don't know if it is possible to get the original source code of the extension used by Chrome or Edge (is it open source, right? so...), customize it, recompiled it and make it default in Chrome/MS-Edge. BTW, my target is MS-Edge because I have been programing other routines in C++ that I need to integrate to it.

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The source code is at where all chromium sources are. In the best case after compiling pdfium you'll need to replace its assets in resources.pak. In the worst case you'll have to compile the entire chromium.

Comment: Thank you wOxxOm. Let say I have finished my customized version of PDFium and compiled it. Then what are the steps to replace it in the resources.pak? I have unpacked the Chrome ver. 88 resources.pak but there is a bunch of png, binarys, and a few js and json files. So how do I know what files I have to replace? I don't know how to correlate the code I can see when I inspect an element with the binary in the resources.pak. Am I missing something?

Comment: That was a guess for something I haven't done myself. I assumed the UI part was there.